# What would a graph where $A\propto Y^2$ look like?

Tags: calculus, physics

Consider a relation between $X$ and $Y$ such that the area under the curve of this was proportional to the square of $Y$, what would such a graph look like.

I was inspired of this question when I was going through my Physics textbook which mentioned such a thing when discussing Current, Voltage, Resistance and it's relationships.

I couldn't find anything online, so if you could point me to some resources and similar things it'd be very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int\limits_{x_0}^x y\,\mathrm{d}y=ky^2\Rightarrow y=2kyy'\Rightarrow y=0\hbox{ or }y'=\frac{1}{2k}\Rightarrow y=0\hbox{ or } y=\frac{x}{2k}+C$ in other words, it's an arbitrary non-vertical line.

Comment: Wow, that's a really cool way to solve this question. Calculus is cool. So let me confirm the working. The first thing you do is differentiate both sides, then solve the differential equation at y = 0. Is this thinking process appropriate?

Comment: "then solve the differential equation" in general case. Right. $y=0$ appears to be a separate solution one have to factor out (one can't cancel by something if it can be $=0$, so we just factor out)

Comment: Also how would we describe the y = 0 solution? Is it something trivial?

Comment: Sure. Then the area is $0$ and all $Y$s are $0$ so it's proportional) It's just the horizontal line passing through origin.